# Разные результаты вывода printf для вещественных чисел

Tags: c, visual-studio, windows-10, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float f = 1717.7890625;
    printf( "%.6f", f );
    return 0;
}
```

Компилирую этот код в Visual Studio 19 (16.9.2) для x64. Получаю разные результаты в Windows 10:

| Version | Debug | Release |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1909 (OS build 18363.1440) | `1717.789063` | `1717.789063` |
| 2004 (OS build 19041.867) | `1717.789063` | `1717.789062` |

В чём причина различий между Debug и Release (`63` и `62` на конце) в новой версии? Как можно исправить ситуацию, чтобы получить одинаковые результаты для обоих версий?

Comment: Please, translate your question into Russian! Пожалуйста, переведите свой вопрос на русский язык!

Comment: Возможно, под 19041.867 у вас разные версии debug|release рантаймов. Приведите версии ucrtbase.dll  и ucrtbased.dll на этой системе.

Comment: Должно выводиться `1717.789062`. Вывод с тройкой на конце — это баг в Universal C Runtime (CRT). Обновите до более новой версии. См.: [printf rounds away from zero instead of to nearest even](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/printf-rounds-away-from-zero-instead-of-to-nearest/325044).